# Maintaining an uncluttered namespace

Tags: python, namespaces

tl;dr: How do I create a new namespace in some `__init__.py`, and copy select bits of another namespace into it, without requiring a sub-module in a new directory?

Full question:

Let's say I have a pair of modules in a package, with the directory structure as follows:

```
foo/mod_1.py
foo/mod_2.py
foo/__init__.py
```

`mod_1.py` is as follows:

```
import numpy

__all__ = ['test1']

def test1():
    return numpy.zeros(10)
```

`mod_2.py` is as follows:

```
import numpy

def test2():
    return numpy.zeros(20)
```

and `__init__.py` as follows:

```
from mod_1 import *
import mod_2

del mod_1
```

This yields more or less the desired namespace:

```
In [7]: dir(foo)
Out[7]: 
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'mod_2',
 'test1']
```

*Except* that `numpy` is now in `foo.mod_2` namespace. If I try to delete it in `__init__.py`, with `del mod_2.numpy`, it no longer exists for that module, so `mod_2.test2` is broken.

I can achieve what I want by creating an extra directory `mod_2` containing `mod_2.py`, but I want to keep the directory structure as-is if possible.

Hence my initial question.

Edit: I don't mind doing a bit of name mangling to stop one name treading on another. Let's say putting the relevant bits of `mod_2.py` into `foo._mod_2`.

Comment: `del mod_1` will raise a `NameError` exception, you didn't import `mod_1`, you imported the names contained *in* `mod_1`.

Comment: Why is it a problem that `mod_2.numpy` exists?

Comment: @MartijnPieters no NameError (I assume because mod_1 is there implicitly as part of the package). Because of OCD sanitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't* want to do that, as you discovered you break your code.

Python is a dynamic language, introspection gives us unfettered access to almost everything the interpreter can reach. This applies to your module too.

If it makes you feel any better, the same thing applies to the standard library:

```
>>> import unittest
>>> unittest.sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> unittest.types
<module 'types' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc'>
>>> dir(unittest)
['FunctionTestCase', 'TestCase', 'TestLoader', 'TestProgram', 'TestResult', 'TestSuite', 'TextTestRunner', '_CmpToKey', '_TextTestResult', '_WritelnDecorator', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__metaclass__', '__name__', '__package__', '__unittest', '__version__', '_makeLoader', '_strclass', 'defaultTestLoader', 'findTestCases', 'getTestCaseNames', 'main', 'makeSuite', 'os', 'sys', 'time', 'traceback', 'types']
```

*Everything* a module needs in it's global namespace can be seen from the outside. **This is normal**.

As you already discovered, use `__all__` to control `from modulename import *` wildcard importing, and leave your module namespace alone otherwise.

Of course, if you want to provide users of your package a clean API, there is nothing stopping you from importing the names that are part of the API into the top-level package `__init__.py`, or by using a `api.py` module.

Importing just means adding the same name as a variable in the current module; `mod_2.numpy` is the exact same thing as `sys.modules['numpy']`, or `numpy` in your current module after you ran `import numpy`.

Comment: So it is, interesting. My initial question is still reasonable though I think - wanting to import some bits of `mod_2.py` into a fresh namespace (let's call it `_mod_2`.

Comment: @HenryGomersall: Then do that, there is nothing stopping you from doing that, right?

Comment: except I don't know how! ;)

Comment: @HenryGomersall: You already did that. You imported names into the top-level `__init__` module. You can also do those same imports into another module. Importing just means adding the same name as a variable in the current module. Perhaps it is not clear what you are trying to achieve otherwise?

Comment: haha! ok, it's obvious now (one easily gets hung up on `__init__.py` as being special). Put it down as a 3 line answer and I'll give you the tick (otherwise I'll do that myself) :)

Comment: @HenryGomersall: I feel like I re-worded my answer in a few different ways already. What part would you like me to reword for you?